# Class constructor being called twice

Tags: c++

I have written the following code, and I can't understand why the Enemy() constructor is called twice. Also as a side question I would like to ask whether overriding member functions by making them virtual and then writing their definitions again is the "correct" way of overriding functions between classes.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Enemy {
    public: Enemy();
    virtual void attack();
};

Enemy::Enemy() {
    cout << "\nEnemy created";

}

void Enemy::attack() {
    cout << "\nattack inflicts 10 damage";

}

class Boss: public Enemy {
    public: Boss();
    virtual void attack();
};

Boss::Boss() {
    cout << "\nYou encounter a boss";
}
void Boss::attack() {
    cout << "\nattack inflicts 30 damage";
}

int main() {
    Enemy enemy1;
    enemy1.attack();
    Boss boss1;
    boss1.attack();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're creating two enemies--one that also happens to be a Boss. So the constructor is called for each Enemy.

Comment: I read that costructors don't pass over in inheritance. Is that what is happening here?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by "don't pass over", but if you mean that base class constructors will still be called, then yes, that's what has to happens. And it makes logical sense too--how else would you be able to initialize private members in the base class?

Comment: @101 Learn how to use a debugger, and step through your code to get a grip what's going on with it!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking for normal behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can't understand why the Enemy() constructor is called twice

Because it inherits it, `Boss` is of type `Enemy`. When you construct a `Boss`, both the constructor of `Boss` and of `Enemy` are invoked.

```
// Redacted lines that aren't important.
Enemy enemy1;
Boss boss1;
```

The above two lines are effectively creating two instances of type `Enemy`. One of them just happens to be a bit more than just an `Enemy`, it's a `Boss`. But it's still also an `Enemy`, and therefore the constructor of `Enemy` is invoked for both objects.

> I would like to ask whether overriding member functions by making them virtual and then writing their definitions again is the "correct" way of overriding functions between classes.

Yes, it is.

Comment: I see. So how do we get past this problem? Not call the Enemy constructor twice?

Comment: You can't! A `Boss` is an `Enemy`!

Comment: It's not a problem. In this particular case, `Enemy` only has a method so calling its constructor seems redundant. However, imagine the case where `Enemy` has a field such as `int hitpoints;`. This field would have to be initialized. If the construction of a `Boss` would not also invoke the constructor of `Enemy` then a `Boss` would have undefined hitpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Since you derived `Boss` from `Enemy`, a `Boss` **is an** `Enemy`. You could think of this as `Boss` having an invisible `Enemy` member inside of it, so when you create a `Boss`, its constructor calls `Enemy`'s to initialize this "invisible" member.

Regarding your second question: yes, but don't forget to annotate this by using keyword **`override`**.

Answer (score 0):

Boss is a child of Enemy. So Enemy's constructor is called before pure Boss's constructor.

```
Boss::Boss() : Enemy ()
{
    cout << "\nYou encounter a boss";
}
```